# GWMI & Registry

Tags: powershell-2.0

When running a 64 bit PS session I find a lot more information than I can in a 32 bit PS session.
In the registry, in a 32 bit PS session, I'm missing some registry keys and in "GWMI win32reg_addremoveprogams (64)" I'm missing some programs. I tried running as administrator and replicating no luck.

Why is this the case? 
Can the information be displaced and located else where?

I'm currently working on a logon script to update a access database with computer information. Which works perfect, except for two pieces of information that can't be located in a 32 bit PS session.

Edit:

Must not require admin.
Must work with PS 2.0.
Value must return to main session.

Comment: See [How to access the 64-bit registry from a 32-bit Powershell instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630382) for various solutions including NET4.0+  `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Registry64` mode

Comment: The script must return a value to main session. Must not have to be ran as admin. And must work with PS 2.0. All good suggestions thanks for the info though