# Powershell: Cannot read a specific Registry-Value

Tags: powershell, registry

I am struggling to read this REG-value via Powershell 5:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/uri:urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/01]
"Driver"="{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}\\0000"
```

Even the autocomplete-function in Powershell showing me the REG-path to that key is not working properly.
Why is it failing? How can I get this value?

This is the code which is surprisingly NOT working as expected:

```
$sub = 'urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/uri:urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/01'
get-Item -literalPath "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\$sub"
```

Here a screenshot of the subkey that I cannot read:
[image]

I could now drill it down to this situation:

1. subkey 'urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42'   -> OK
2. subkey 'uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/u'     -> OK
3. subkey 'urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/u' -> fail!
4. subkey 'urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/u' under HKLM:\Software -> OK

Comment: Also, registry values are not obtainable with `Get-ChildItem`, that works only for subkeys. You must use `Get-ItemProperty` for values.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for the input, but that is not the origin of the problem. Its the subkey wich seems to block any reg-command here. That includes get-item, get-childitem, get-itemproperty and get-itempropertyvalue.

Comment: What if you escape the `:` and slashes in the key name by prefixing them with a backtick ``"`"`` ? Did you check permissions on that key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it turns out, that I had to use a different Syntax for the REG-Path to make the call work - very strange!

See this code:

```
$prefix1 = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
$prefix2 = "HKLM:"
$subDir = "urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/uri:urn:uuid:cfe92100-67c4-11d4-a45f-0026abfabc42/01"
get-item "$prefix1\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\$subDir"
get-item "$prefix2\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\$subDir"
```

The first "get-item" call using prefix1 is working fine while the second one is not returning anything back.

Lession learned: Better use the longer REG-Prefix like in the original PSPATH to avoid any unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sysinternals Process Explorer, I've discovered what happens.

PowerShell replaces the forward slashes in the path unconditionally with backslashes, even when you use `-LiteralPath`.

[image: Screenshot of failing registry access]

That's clearly a bug.

To work around it, you can use the `PSPath` of the registry key, apparently PowerShell leaves those alone. For the local registry, the `PSPath` always starts like this:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::
```

and after that goes on with the regular key name as it would appear in RegEdit.

```
$path = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider\urn:uuid:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c83410f/uri:e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c83410f/PrinterService"

Get-Item $path
```

PSPaths are an integral part of anything that Powershell treats as one of its drives. You can select them, or access the `.PSPath` property:

```
$path = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\DAFWSDProvider"

Get-ChildItem $path | Select -ExpandProperty PSPath

(Get-Item C:\).PSPath
```

Comment: We both posted a solution in parallel ;-) Many thanks for your great support!

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's PowerShell documentation, you can decide if you would like to view the entries as a list or to retrieve a single registry key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I have read about if you are using a 32 bit version of PowerShell. You may have problems accessing 64 bit registry keys. If the following webpage applies, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630382/how-to-access-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-powershell-instance

Comment: Nope. Also, as mentioned above, if I rename the subkey a bit I can read it, but not with the name as it is right now.